# Do professors recommend their students on LinkedIn?

Tags: recommendation-letter, networking, social-media

Do professors recommend their students on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com)? If they do recommend, isn't it considered a violation of [FERPA](http://www2.ed.gov/policy/gen/guid/fpco/ferpa/index.html)?

Professors are typically required to recommend without fear or inhibition towards the student who he is recommending. A professor will be much more candid with his recommendation when his student waives his rights to see his recommendation. In that case recommendations on LinkedIn are probably a waste for academia right?

What would your opinion be on taking a letter of recommendation from a professor who has already recommended you on LinkedIn then?

> Third, the letter of recommendation, when completed, becomes an
>   education record.  Both the paper copy and e-file are education
>   records… and it makes no difference where they are filed.  Since FERPA
>   grants the student the right to inspect any education record, there is
>   also an unwritten obligation to notify the writer of this right.
>
> In this latter instance, the placement office, or student, should
>   initially provide each writer with the knowledge that the student has
>   either waived, or not waived, his right to subsequently review the
>   letter.  This knowledge may influence what the writer includes in the
>   letter.  It may persuade the person to whom a reference request was
>   made to politely decline to write the letter.  Unfortunately, letter
>   writers do not have the same rights that students have in the
>   letter-writing process.

Therefore , students generally waive their rights to view their letters of recommendation. Now, when you post a recommendation on LinkedIn, it will be displayed(provided the student accepts the recommendation). This might actually influence the writer of the letter to write a more positive recommendation than intended for the the student.

Now, an influenced letter is probably a waste for academia right? Or for any kind of work at all?

And if a professor is candid in his LinkedIn recommendation and mentions the student's performance objectively(say perhaps about the student's grades) then it does become a violation of FERPA right?

This is what I'd like to ask Professors in Academia now: If a student asks for a LinkedIn Recommendation , will it hold any value?

Comment: Could you be more specific: in what way do you think it is a violation of FERPA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have, in the past, recommended students on LinkedIn, when requested by them. This applies, in particular, to PhD students shortly before or after their defense, who were looking for a position outside academia and in the private sector. In chemical engineering, the situation of that academics tend not to use LinkedIn for looking up/assessing prospective hires, while it is widely used outside academia (and I believe this is true of other fields).

For this reason, I maintain a small presence on LinkedIn myself, because:

1. This is one of the ways I can help (by networking and recommendations) my former students find a job, which is part of a PhD adviser’s responsibilities.
2. I might want a job outside academia at some point in my career, too!

---

Regarding FERPA compliance, I am not US-based so I have little knowledge about it. This [webpage](http://www.capd.k-state.edu/about/policies/ferpa-compliance-for-recommendation-letter-writers) on “FERPA Compliance [for] Recommendation Letter Writers” implies that compliance mostly puts constraints on the content of the letter (which should not include “education records”).