# A LinkedIn Recommendation as compared to an Academic Recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter, social-media

In what ways would a Professor's LinkedIn Recommendation differ from his Recommendation for Graduate School(Masters/PhD)?

In other words: In what was does the visibility of a Recommendation change a Professor's Recommendation?

Comment: related http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5106/do-professors-recommend-their-students-on-linkedin

Comment: I asked that question. I believe this is fundamentally different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe they are totally different.

- LinkedIn recommendation is more towards the visibility of student's soft/technical skills in general while the official letter of recommendation should address the student skills in a more academic/depth way.
- Their audience is different. Recommendation Letter is intended to particular institute/committee while LinkedIn is more to the public general and industry recruiters in particular.
- LinkedIn recommendations counts nothing for the admission committees while might have good impact on industry recruiters.

In short: Academia:- Recommendation Letters. Industry: doesn't hurt to let your supervisor recommending you - if they do have account on LinkedIn :-)

Comment: be prepared for professors to say no to a LinkedIn recommendation, some of them feel that it may open them up to potential FERPA violations.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing LinkedIn recommendations may require to register and login. Just because you have a LinkedIn account, does not mean your employer has.

As a result, I would suggest to include the full text of the LinkedIn recommendation, not just a reference to it. But then it becomes not much different from just an ordinary recommendation that is just placed for public viewing on some website.